# How can I connect UaExpert with docker container?

Tags: docker, opc, opc-ua

I have started successful a OpcUa Server in a docker container. Now I want to connect to this container via UaExpert.
But this is not working:

> Message: Could not connect to server:BadTimeout

I created a own subnet (pa1net) and want use the ip 192.123.0.32.

My command: `docker run --net pa1net --ip 192.123.0.32 -it pa1`

Output:

```
**********************************************
Server opened enpoints for following URLs:
        opc.tcp://2e54ds688fd4:48010
**********************************************
```

But this url `opc.tcp://2e5...` contains the docker container id (2e54ds688fd4) and that isn't ok ?!

When I `ping` the ip 192.123.0.32 I get packages back.

I do not know which URL / IP is the correct one to connect to the container...

Or is my command wrong to connect to a container ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This container located behind nat. You need to publish port or be the same docker network. Or you have to correct your route.

Comment: now its running! I did it with publish! Thank you =)